# Nullable enable with collection of T

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I'm currently working on enabling the nullable option on one of our company projects, and I'm not sure how to handle the following situation.

```
public class MyCollection<T>
{
    private T[] myArray;
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get => myArray[i];
        set => myArray[i] = value;
    }
}
```

If T is a reference type, I want null to be a valid value. But in case of a value type, I don't want `Nullable<T>` to be involved, keep the type as is.

I tried playing with annotations, but in the end if `value` can be null in the setter, I'm forced to declare `myArray` as a `T?[]`.

```
public class MyCollection<T>
{
    private T[];
    [AllowNull]
    public T this[int i]
    {
        [return: MaybeNull]
        get => myArray[i];
        set => myArray[i] = value; // Possibly null
    }
}
```

So I guess my questions are :

- If I make `myArray` a `T?[]`, will the compiler enforce the use of `Nullable<T>` for value types ?
- If that is the case, is there a way to do what I want to ?

Comment: Use the null-forgiving operator in conjunction with `MaybeNull`: `myArray[i] = value!`.

Comment: Note that `[return: MaybeNull]` doesn't work on property getters; an assignment like `string s = collection[5]` will not warn. To make this work properly you must apply `[MaybeNull]` to the property as a whole. (`AllowNull` is still also required, as that only applies to the setter.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ok good to know too, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# 9 you can apply `?` to an "unconstrained generic type" and it won't produce `Nullable<T>` if `T` is a `struct`.

So your example becomes:

```cs
public class MyCollection<T>
{
    private T?[] myArray;
    public T? this[int i]
    {
        get => myArray[i];
        set => myArray[i] = value;
    }
}
```

The attributes work too, but are less elegant.

Comment: I did some additional testing and you're right, the simplest way was the right one 